# Xcode 11 header file issue

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm pretty new to using Xcode with C++ development. For some reason, the compiler isn't treating .h files correctly. It doesn't color code correctly, nor does it highlight compile-time errors. I've tried looking through the settings to see if I can change this, and I found that it treats .h files by default as c-headers. I changed this to C++ header file in one of them to see if this would help, and then closed the project and reopened. Nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to rename your files to .hpp ?

Comment: I did this and closed and reopened. No change.